# FormGroup ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to get a value from my form and I am getting this error:
  *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined*

```
 addMessage: FormGroup;
 get message(){ return this.addMessage.get('message').value}
```

Html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="addMessage" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage()">
      <input formControlName="message" class="input" type="text">
      <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Send</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: did you define this.addMessage = new FormGroup() in ngOnInit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You did was everything right, but you need to build a FormBuilder too.

Kindly follow my method of getting data from a form.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="WordpressForm">

 <div class="form-group">
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input matInput placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]='title' formControlName='title'>
   </mat-form-field>
   <div>        
   <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

ts:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

WordpressForm = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', [Validators.required]]
});

getTitle() {
 return this.WordpressForm.get('title');
}

save() {
 const template_Title = this.title;
 console.log(template_Title);
}
```

Comment: I have done same as per above still getting this error on every API hit.Any Solution ?

Comment: @MayurSaner can you please elaborate more .. any code snippets ? and + do remember to check all the imports are proper or not (dependencies)

Comment: Is this not improperly mixing Reactive Forms with Template Driven forms with the use of [(ngModel)]?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
return this.addMessage.controls['message'].value
```

For more information you can [play here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/epxddaaorpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-form%2Fhero-form.component.ts) on official playground of form in angular

Comment: ChatMessagesComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @Gallo Please check this now.

Comment: @Gallo sorry my mistake, forgot to add `controls` for form. PLease check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

...

addMessage = new FormGroup({
    message: new FormControl()
});

get message(){ 
  const messageControl = this.addMessage.controls['message'];
  return messageControl.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd suggest is this:

First: Import the ReactiveFormsModule into the module that offers the component (the one you are importing the component that has the form into)

Second: Import FormGroup and FormBuilder into your form component

Third: declare the variable that will be your form name, as such:
`public myFormName: FormGroup;`

Pleace notice that I have given the variable the FormGroup type. At the template, you will assign the content of your form to this variable (make sure it is public, not private), like this:

```
  <form [formGroup]="myFormName">
```

Forth: Declare, at the component's constructor, a private variable with the type "FormBuilder", as such:

```
constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder)
```

Fifth: create a public method that will 'create' your reactive form, something like this:

```
createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        name: [''],
        gender: [''],
        birth_date: ['']
      },
    );
  }
```

Make sure the property name maps a `formControlName` in your template. Initialize each property with a ' ' value, or the initial value you want it to have (make sure it is of the same type declared on the template)

Last: Call the form creation method on the component's constructor, so the form will be instantiated when the template renders.

Bonus round: If your form is simple, consider using template driven forms. Reactive forms are more robust, and meant to be used when you need to have more control over your form.

Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

define instance

```
addMessage: FormGroup;

this.addMessage = new FormGroup({

      message: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])  });


get getMeassageValue() {
    return this.addMessage.get('message').value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with name of form whether it is matching in HTML file and in Typescript file where the formbuilder group is initialized.

In my case this was the only mistake.

**app.component.html**

````
<form [formGroup]="FormName">
    ```
    ```
</form>
````

**app.component.ts**

```
FormName = this.fb.group({
    name: [],
    age: [],
    city: [],
})
```

The **FormName** should be uniform throughout.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with this question, in my case, what worked was add a:

```html
if (this.form) {
 //get function
}
```

And the code will assume that it can only get it if exists.